# Emit g_signal from thread to main in Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, glib, pygobject

So I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/bossjones/e21b53c6dff04e8fdb3d) on how to create a "thread pooling" system and my issue is: when the executed function finished in the thread the "completed" signal must be emitted from (or to) the main thread. The solution presented on the gist was to overwrite `GObject.emit` function using `GObject.idle_add(GObject.GObject.emit, self, *args)` which does the trick in the gist example, but misteriously does not work for me. I created a slightly modified version of his code that does what I need, except from emitting the signals correctly/at all.

```
class _IdleObject(GObject.GObject):
    """ Override GObject.GObject to always emit signals in the main thread by
    emmitting on an idle handler """
    @trace
    def __init__(self):
        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)

    @trace
    def emit(self, *args):
        GLib.idle_add(GObject.GObject.emit, self, *args)
```

In summary, the signals are either not emitted or emitted on secondary threads (when the emit function overwrite is commented out) which can't update the UI therefore don't solve my problem. Any ideas on what's going on?

My version of his gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/raggesilver/aa63fe46ea6b736a036f90ff36aa3c71)

Comment: Are you definitely running a main loop in your main thread? You say you’ve got a UI, and if that’s using GTK+ then you will have a main loop running. But this is the first thing to check.

Comment: Yes it's `Gtk.main`

Comment: Have you tried calling `GLib.idle_add()` with your own callback function, which prints a message when invoked? That would allow you to work out whether the problem is with the chained `GObject.GObject.emit` call, or with the idle callback itself.

Comment: In fact I have, the message isn't printed at all

Comment: If you print a message from your `_IdleObject.emit()` method, is that printed?

Comment: Duuuuude, this is so messed up, my program actually has a main loop but turns out I was testing the threads module alone (not running the main loop) LMAO. So sorry for wasting your time, and thanks a lot for the help @PhilipWithnall